# What is the size of Local notification custom image icon in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Normally the `App icon`, show as the `Push Notification` image icon (Left side). But if I want to add a custom image in my `Push Notification`, is there any fixed size of the image I have to follow?
Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has the same size as the Launch Images you usually provide your app with.

- 3.5": 640*960
- 4": 640*1136

etc..

Here's some description provided by Apple:

> The string is a filename of an image file in the app bundle. This
>   image is a launching image specified for a given notification; when
>   the user taps the action button (for example, “View”) or moves the
>   action slider, the image is used in place of the default launching
>   image. If the value of this property is nil (the default), the system
>   either uses the previous snapshot, uses the image identified by the
>   UILaunchImageFile key in the app’s Info.plist file, or falls back to
>   Default.png.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertLaunchImage

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Usually it shows the icon of the Apps, If I didn't set it manually. Are you sure it will be `Launch image`! or `Icon image` of the Apps? @Dani A

Comment: Launch Image of course. @Tulon , I edited my answer for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yes, It clearly says it should be the `Launch image` of the Apps. But the most ironic thing is, I just checked all of my Notifications both in iPhone & iPad individually, but none of them use their `Launch image` as Notification icon. Don't know were they used the custom icon or not. May be yes, And set the Apps icon there as Notification icon. :)
I would prefer the size of App icon though. It perfectly fits in a square position. Again Thanks. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If you check apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW15

There is nothing in the notification payload to allow the use of a custom image. I think that you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm talking about the Local Notification. Yes, It can be done there. Just want to know the exact size of the image, like width and height in pixel. @gabuh

Comment: @Tulon are you sure?, then it should be of the size of the spotlight icon... 29x29 in non-retina devices. Please show me how can you do it... I would like to learn something new... ^_^

Comment: Let me give you the code:

`UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];`

`if (notification)
    {
        // If you not set image, then it shows the apps default icon here
        notification.alertLaunchImage = @"icon.png";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }`

But I'm little bit confuse here. I have already used 29X29, but it shows a very poor quality. Then use the Apps icon image size 512x512, it shows perfectly. Though, @Dani A, saying below, it should be the `Launch image`. But still, I have to know the correct dimension.

Comment: @Tulon But, what are you trying to change?, the notification icon?,  or the LaunchImage that shows when you tap on the notification?. alertLaunchImage: `Identifies the image used as the launch image when the user taps (or slides) the action button (or slider).` That is not the notification icon...

Comment: Then you can't, the notification icon is the app icon, and can't be changed, link in your post a pic if you are managing to change it in someway, because, as far as I know, it's not possible.